# Direct2d access violation in C++ XAML game

Tags: c++, xaml, windows-phone, directx

I have created an Windows Phone game in C++ (native only) using the DirectXToolkit and wanted to recreate this app using XAML and C++.

I followed all the steps from [this](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/DirectX_on_Windows_Phone%3a_2D_Game_Example_using_DirectX_Toolkit) tutorial but got stuck on the following problem.

In the `void Renderer::CreateDeviceResources()` function I am calling `m_spriteBatch = unique_ptr<SpriteBatch>(new DirectX::SpriteBatch(m_d3dContext.Get()));`

This is, however, causing a problem in `MainPage.xaml.cs` inside the `DrawingSurfaceBackground_Loaded` function at the line `DrawingSurfaceBackground.SetBackgroundContentProvider(m_d3dBackground.CreateContentProvider());`

I am getting an `An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Unknown Module. Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.`

When removing the `m_spriteBatch...` line everything is starting fine but then I can't render my sprites in the game.

Any idea how to fix this? I am new to C++ so I don't really know where to look.

Comment: If you get a stack trace, do post the relevant portion. That might help sort this problem out.

Comment: I wanted to post a stack trace but it's null :(

Comment: Ouch! I'll try to read more of the tutorial and try to figure this out. Hopefully someone having more experience in these technologies will help out.

Comment: It's not really about the tutorial... It's more about the line in the CreateDeviceResources() which I highlighted. It works fine when doing a native only app but don't when I work with XAML and C++. Thanks for trying!

Comment: Please try m_d3dContext.Get() by itself and let me know if that causes the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess, but perhaps you cannot instantiate using "new" as you are doing:

```
(new DirectX::SpriteBatch(m_d3dContext.Get()))
```

In this case, *new* is allocating memory to the heap.  Could this be causing the memory access violation?

Comment: Changed it to this:
`m_spriteBatch = unique_ptr<SpriteBatch>(&DirectX::SpriteBatch(m_d3dContext.Get()));` but getting the same error :(

Comment: You say you are creating m_spriteBatch inside of the function Renderer::CreateDeviceResources() -- is there a scope issue?

Comment: There shouldn't be. Because I have successfully tested the app as a native only app.